# how to display the contents of an object array

Tags: php

i have an object array  from
 Sql group_concat()

```
while($row=$result->fetch_object(  ))
  { echo  $rows->PreviousV ;}
```

which has a comma delimited string ie xxxxxx,yyyyyy
how can I loop through it using php and display its contents as links?

Comment: @donose there you now have an update

Comment: @manwal there is your update so far

Comment: `foreach(explode(',',$rows->PreviousV) as $value) { echo $value; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). It will produce an array then you can list them using foreach.

for instance:

```
$input = "hello,there";
foreach($input as $index=>$key)
{
  echo $key;
}
```

output:

```
hello
there
```